# How to use a font embedded in a SWC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, flash-builder, swc

I exported a SWC from Flash CS3 with a font embedded.

Now I want use it in some TextFields, but I don't know how to use the font.

Comment: Why don't you embed font into flex directly with @embed directive? Why do you use intermediate SWC media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! Here's my solution:

```
[Embed(source="res/guardanapo.otf", fontName="guardanapo", fontFamily="guardanapo", unicodeRange="U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E", advancedAntiAliasing="false", embedAsCFF="false")]
public static const fonte:Class;
```

I wanted to embed the font from SWC, but now it isn't necessary anymore. But answer if you know how to do that, maybe someone is serching for it now.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. myLoader is the loader that you loaded your swf/swc with the font in its library. myTextField is a pre-existing text field. I set embedFonts to true, but you may not need it.

```
var MyFont:Class = myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("FontClassName");

var embeddedFont:Font = new MyFont();

var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.font = embeddedFont.fontName;
textFormat.size = 24;

myTextField.setTextFormat(textFormat);
myTextField.embedFonts = true;
```

Maybe you can include a font-fetching class in the swf with the font(s) you want to use. There could be static methods that apply a font to a field, or return the font name given the font's class name. This could help keep the rest of your application cleaner.